# Geoserver variable substitution is possible for textsymbolizer?

Tags: geoserver

I'm using geoserver version `2.6` .

I can change polygon style from openlayers map page with variable substitution parameters.

Here is sample:

```
<Fill>
   <CssParameter name="fill">
      #<ogc:Function name="env">
        <ogc:Literal>color</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>AAAAAA</ogc:Literal>
     </ogc:Function>
    </CssParameter>
</Fill>`
```

My question is:
How can I use these option for textsymbolizer?